# homology of punctured manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, manifolds

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional closed manifold. Choose $x \in M$. Using long exact sequence of pairs $(M,M - x)$, we have
$$H_k(M - x, \mathbb{Z}) \cong H_k(M, \mathbb{Z})$$
for $k<n-1$. For $k=n-1$, I see this is an isomorphism with $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficient. I am curious if there is an example that they are not isomorphic with integer coefficient.

[edit] I was assuming orientability. In the long exact sequence with $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficient
$$H_n(M) \rightarrow H_n(M, M-x) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(M-x) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(M) \rightarrow 0,$$
the first map is an isomorphism so the third is an isomorphism. Sorry for stupid question.

Comment: Try $\mathbb{RP}^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also an isomorphism with $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients. One way to see it is to use the "open-closed" exact sequence
$$H^0(M,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^0(\{x\} ,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^1_c(M-x,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^1(M,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow 0$$
and Poincaré duality which identifies the last (nontrivial) arrow with $H_{n-1}(M-x,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H_{n-1}(M,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: This answer assumes the manifold is orientable. In general the map in questions is not an isomorphism as the example of the projective plane shows.

Comment: Right, I was indeed assuming $M$ orientable.

Comment: Thank you. I was assuming $M$ orientable, too. Could you let me know the reference of the exact sequence?

Comment: There must be many; one I know (in the more general context of sheaf theory) is in Dimca's book *Sheaves in Topology* (Universitext, Springer), Remark 2.4.5.